# Removing Left Recursion from CFG

Tags: recursion, context-free-grammar, left-recursion

The following grammar has left recursion:

```
T -> Tx | TYx | YX | x
X -> xx
Y -> Yy | Yx | y
```

How do you go about removing left recursion.  I read the wikipedia explanation, but I'm fairly new to CFGs so it did not make a lot of sense.  Any help is appreciated?  A plain english explanation would be even more appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

In this example, you can follow Robert C. Moore's [general algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion#Removing_left_recursion) to convert a rule with left recursion to a rule with right recursion:

```
A -> A a1 | A a2 | ... | b1 | b2 | ...
# converts to
A  -> b1 A' | b2 A' | ...
A' -> e | a1 A' | a2 A' | ...                 # where e = epsilon
```

*In our first case:* `A=T, a1=x, a2=Yx, b1=y, b2=x`... (similarly for `Y`)

```
T  -> YXT' | xT'
T' -> e | xT' | YxT'
X  -> xx
Y  -> yY'
Y' -> e | yY' | xY'
```

Comment: isn't `YXT'` still left recursive? Likewise for `YxT'` & `YxY'`? Or am I missing something.  Thanks for this.  It is very helpful.

Comment: Or is not left recursive since the left side of those elements lead to different non-terminals other than where it originates from?

Comment: `T' -> YxT'` is right recursive but not left (there is no way to have T' on the left-hand-side). Oooops: `YxY'` was a typo (corrected to `xY'`).